# RHEL - Group assigned incorrectly

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, group

In our lab, all the LDAP users are assigned to a group **vboxusers** whose home directory is present in the server. We are using NFS to mount the home directory of an user to the client machines. I was installing a new client machine and added it to the network. I configured the LDAP in this new machine and strangely there was a group **cimsrvr** which was assigned the same ID as **vboxusers** in the remaining client machines.

In the newly installed machine, I find the below entry in **/etc/group** file.

```
cimsrvr: 501
```

In all of the remaining client machines, I find the entry in **/etc/group** file as,

```
vboxusers: 501
```

I was assigning permission to all the users belonging to **vboxusers** to access *Virtualbox*. When I assigned the permissions to **cimsrvr** in the new machine, the vboxusers were able to access *Virtualbox* without any problem. So, I figured out the group name is just for our understanding and the machine just uses the group ID. That's why all the users belonging to group 501 were able to access *VirtualBox*.

My question is, how did the **cimsrvr** group got assigned to 501 in the first place when I did not create any group by that name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group IDs (the numbers) are arbitrarily assigned when RPMs are installed, unless the package explicitly adds these entries specifying a specific GID number.

#### Example

From a Fedora 14 system.

```
$ more /etc/group
vboxusers:x:502:saml
jetty:x:485:
xfs:x:43:
kvm:x:36:qemu
qemu:x:107:
```

To migrate these groups to another GID you'll have to search the disk for all occurrences and then `chgrp <new GID>` to move them to some unused number.

Comment: oh ok. So, was I correct in my understanding that the machine looks only for group ID rather than the group name? Because, when I assigned permissions to **cimsrvr** with group ID 501, I was able to access the Virtualbox application.

Comment: The names are essentially just labels for the GID numbers. The numbers are what really matter on the disk, in most cases. There are some situations where the name does matter though.

Comment: Perfect. I am learning new things each and every day. God, I am starting to love Linux.